# Arduino Can't run After Unplug and Replug or Reset

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano

I am using Arduino nano 33 IoT and currently my Arduino stops running even the loop function after unplug&Replug into the computer without reprogramming or pressing the reset button. Any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Sample Code: The follow code stops printing "hello" to the serial port after unplugging and re-plugging or pressing the reset button on board.

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  while (!Serial);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  Serial.println("hello");
}
```

Comment: it changes the com port and then it waits for the connection to Serial Monitor on `while (!Serial);`

Comment: I have already tried the solution here to fix the port, but same problem appears. Any further suggestions?      https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360016420140-COM-port-number-changes-when-connecting-board-on-different-ports-or-in-bootloader-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Remove line `while (!Serial);`
2. Reopen a new serial monitor whenever you reset/re-plugin in order to see the serial output!